# How to set $dataProvider after AJAX in kartik yii2-export?

Tags: yii2, export-to-csv, kartik-v

How to set or refresh $dataProvider with AJAX?

```
echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
]);
```

After AJAX contents of list does not update remains same as i loaded page for the first time.